# Issue combining makecell and cellcolor

Tags: tables, makecell, cellcolor

I have seen similar question to this one already but none of the answers I have found seem to solve my problem. I'm trying to color the cells of the first column of my table, but I cannot find a correct way to do this. I tried using `\cellcolor` and `>{\columncolor{LightGrey}}` but both of them led to the same results.

```
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper,article]{memoir}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[french,english]{babel}
    \usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames, table, svgnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{diagbox}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{stackengine}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \newcommand\xrowht[2][0]{\addstackgap[.5\dimexpr#2\relax]{\vphantom{#1}}}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|*{5}{c|}}\hline
    \rowcolor{LightGrey}
    \backslashbox[50mm]{Algorithms}{Metrics}
    &\makebox[4em]{Accuracy} &\makebox[4em]{Precision} & \makebox[4em]{Recall} & \makebox[4em]{F1 score} &\makebox[4em]{F2 score}\\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{LightGrey}\makecell{Neural Network \\ with Embedding} & 0.62 & 0.23 & 0.82 & 0.36 & 0.54\\
    \hline
    \makecell{Neural Network \\ without Embedding} & 0.64 & 0.22 & 0.69 & 0.34 & 0.49\\
    \hline
    \makecell{Support Vector Machine \\ (SVM)} & 0.64 & 0.21 & 0.65 &0.32 & 0.46\\
    \hline\xrowht{20pt}
    \makebox[4em]{Logistic Regression} & 0.60 & 0.17 & 0.55 & 0.26 & 0.38\\
    \hline\xrowht{20pt}
    \makebox[4em]{Decision tree} & 0.72 & 0.25 & 0.56 & 0.34 & 0.46\\
    \hline\xrowht{20pt}
    \makebox[4em]{Random Forest} & 0.77 & 0.27 & 0.43 & 0.33 & 0.38\\
    \hline\xrowht{20pt}
    \makebox[4em]{XGBoost} & 0.71 & 0.27 & 0.75 & 0.4 & 0.56\\
    \hline\xrowht{20pt}
    \makebox[4em]{CatBoost} & 0.70 & 0.27 & 0.75 & 0.39 & 0.55\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Results using Weight Attention Data Set.}
    \label{tab:tableweightattention}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

trying with `>{\columncolor{LightGrey}}`

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\xrowht[2][0]{\addstackgap[.5\dimexpr#2\relax]{\vphantom{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{LightGrey}}c|*{5}{c|}}\hline
\rowcolor{LightGrey}
\backslashbox[50mm]{Algorithms}{Metrics}
&\makebox[4em]{Accuracy} &\makebox[4em]{Precision} & \makebox[4em]{Recall} & \makebox[4em]{F1 score} &\makebox[4em]{F2 score}\\
\hline
\makecell{Neural Network \\ with Embedding} & 0.62 & 0.23 & 0.82 & 0.36 & 0.54\\
\hline
\makecell{Neural Network \\ without Embedding} & 0.64 & 0.22 & 0.69 & 0.34 & 0.49\\
\hline
\makecell{Support Vector Machine \\ (SVM)} & 0.64 & 0.21 & 0.65 &0.32 & 0.46\\
\hline\xrowht{20pt}
\makebox[4em]{Logistic Regression} & 0.60 & 0.17 & 0.55 & 0.26 & 0.38\\
\hline\xrowht{20pt}
\makebox[4em]{Decision tree} & 0.72 & 0.25 & 0.56 & 0.34 & 0.46\\
\hline\xrowht{20pt}
\makebox[4em]{Random Forest} & 0.77 & 0.27 & 0.43 & 0.33 & 0.38\\
\hline\xrowht{20pt}
\makebox[4em]{XGBoost} & 0.71 & 0.27 & 0.75 & 0.4 & 0.56\\
\hline\xrowht{20pt}
\makebox[4em]{CatBoost} & 0.70 & 0.27 & 0.75 & 0.39 & 0.55\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Results using Weight Attention Data Set.}
% \label{tab:tableweightattention}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If anyone has an idea about what I'm doing wrong or has solution to this problem, you would be my hero.

Following @leandriis comment I tried using the `nicematrix`, but does not seems to take care of the `\makebox`. I would like to increase the size of the header box, i did not find anything on the documentation. Here is the code and the new table obtained:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand\xrowht[2][0]{\addstackgap[.5\dimexpr#2\relax]{\vphantom{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|>{\columncolor{LightGrey}}c|*{5}{c|}}\hline
\rowcolor{LightGrey}
\makebox[4em]{\diagbox{Algorithms}{Metrics}} &\makebox[4em]{Accuracy} &\makebox[4em]{Precision} & \makebox[4em]{Recall} & \makebox[4em]{F1 score} &\makebox[4em]{F2 score}\\
\hline
\makecell{Neural Network \\ with Embedding} & 0.62 & 0.23 & 0.82 & 0.36 & 0.54\\
\hline
\makecell{Neural Network \\ without Embedding} & 0.64 & 0.22 & 0.69 & 0.34 & 0.49\\
\hline
\makecell{Support Vector Machine \\ (SVM)} & 0.64 & 0.21 & 0.65 &0.32 & 0.46\\
\hline\xrowht{20pt}
\makebox[4em]{Logistic Regression} & 0.60 & 0.17 & 0.55 & 0.26 & 0.38\\
\hline\xrowht{20pt}
\makebox[4em]{Decision tree} & 0.72 & 0.25 & 0.56 & 0.34 & 0.46\\
\hline\xrowht{20pt}
\makebox[4em]{Random Forest} & 0.77 & 0.27 & 0.43 & 0.33 & 0.38\\
\hline\xrowht{20pt}
\makebox[4em]{XGBoost} & 0.71 & 0.27 & 0.75 & 0.4 & 0.56\\
\hline\xrowht{20pt}
\makebox[4em]{CatBoost} & 0.70 & 0.27 & 0.75 & 0.39 & 0.55\\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I finally managed to obtain the desired results, thanks everyone!

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand\xrowht[2][0]{\addstackgap[.5\dimexpr#2\relax]{\vphantom{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering

\begin{NiceTabular}{c*{5}{wc{4em}}}[ code-before = \columncolor{LightGrey}{1} \rowcolor{LightGrey}{1} , hvlines ]
\xrowht{20pt}
\diagbox{Algorithms}{Metrics} & Accuracy &Precision & Recall & F1 score &F2 score\\
\makecell{Neural Network \\ with Embedding} & 0.62 & 0.23 & 0.82 & 0.36 & 0.54\\
\makecell{Neural Network \\ without Embedding} & 0.64 & 0.22 & 0.69 & 0.34 & 0.49\\
\makecell{Support Vector Machine \\ (SVM)} & 0.64 & 0.21 & 0.65 &0.32 & 0.46\\
\xrowht{20pt}
Logistic Regression & 0.60 & 0.17 & 0.55 & 0.26 & 0.38\\
\xrowht{20pt}
Decision tree & 0.72 & 0.25 & 0.56 & 0.34 & 0.46\\
\xrowht{20pt}
Random Forest & 0.77 & 0.27 & 0.43 & 0.33 & 0.38\\
\xrowht{20pt}
XGBoost & 0.71 & 0.27 & 0.75 & 0.4 & 0.56\\
\xrowht{20pt}
CatBoost & 0.70 & 0.27 & 0.75 & 0.39 & 0.55\\
\end{NiceTabular}

\caption{Results using Weight Attention Data Set.}
\label{tab:tableweightattention}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the `NiceTabular` environment from the `nicematrix` package.

Comment: @leandriis thanks for telling me about this package, if you have any insight on how I can modify the size of a given row it would be awesome!

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: @AndréC Hi and thank you, I updated the last 2 code snippet, should be better know.

Comment: @Netim  can you use xrowht

Comment: @jsbibra Yes indeed by doing so i obtain the result that is wished for! Thanks

Comment: This is a bug in `\makecell` as it seems. Did anyone already report that bug to the author, actually? The proper solution would be fixing that package…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with makecell and colouring tables has been known for quite some time. A simple possibility, consists in replacing `\makecell` in coloured columns/rows with `\Centerstack` from `stackengine`. I took the opportunity to simplify a bit your code (the default input encoding is now utf8, for instance, so needless to load `inputenc`) and added some improvelments, `S`type columns for the alignment on the decimal dot, and loading of `v=cellspace` to add some vertical padding to multiline cells in the first column.

```
   \documentclass[12pt, a4paper,article]{memoir}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[french,english]{babel}
    \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{siunitx} 
    \usepackage[dvipsnames, table, svgnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{diagbox}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
    \usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
    \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2pt}
    \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2pt}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \newcommand\xrowht[2][0]{\addstackgap[.5\dimexpr#2\relax]{\vphantom{#1}}}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \sisetup{table-format=1.2, table-column-width = 4em, table-number-alignment=center}
    \begin{tabular}{| >{\columncolor{LightGrey}}Oc|*{5}{S|}}\hline
    \rowcolor{LightGrey}
   \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ \backslashbox[50mm]{Algorithms}{Metrics}}
    &{Accuracy} &{Precision} & {Recall} &{F1 score} &{F2 score}\\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{LightGrey}\Centerstack{Neural Network \\ with Embedding} & 0.62 & 0.23 & 0.82 & 0.36 & 0.54\\
    \hline
    \Centerstack{Neural Network \\ without Embedding} & 0.64 & 0.22 & 0.69 & 0.34 & 0.49\\
    \hline
    \Centerstack{Support Vector Machine \\ (SVM)} & 0.64 & 0.21 & 0.65 &0.32 & 0.46\\
    \hline\xrowht{20pt}
    Logistic Regression & 0.60 & 0.17 & 0.55 & 0.26 & 0.38\\
    \hline\xrowht{20pt}
    Decision tree & 0.72 & 0.25 & 0.56 & 0.34 & 0.46\\
    \hline\xrowht{20pt}
    Random Forest & 0.77 & 0.27 & 0.43 & 0.33 & 0.38\\
    \hline\xrowht{20pt}
     XGBoost & 0.71 & 0.27 & 0.75 & 0.4 & 0.56\\
    \hline\xrowht{20pt}
     CatBoost & 0.70 & 0.27 & 0.75 & 0.39 & 0.55\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Results using Weight Attention Data Set.}
    \label{tab:tableweightattention}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{c*{5}{wc{4em}}}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=1mm]
\CodeBefore
  \columncolor{LightGrey}{1} 
  \rowcolor{LightGrey}{1} 
\Body
  \diagbox{Algorithms}{Metrics}
  &Accuracy &Precision &Recall &F1 score &F2 score \\
  \Block{}{Neural Network \\ with Embedding} & 0.62 & 0.23 & 0.82 & 0.36 & 0.54\\
  \Block{}{Neural Network \\ without Embedding} & 0.64 & 0.22 & 0.69 & 0.34 & 0.49\\
  \Block{}{Support Vector Machine \\ (SVM)} & 0.64 & 0.21 & 0.65 &0.32 & 0.46\\
  Logistic Regression & 0.60 & 0.17 & 0.55 & 0.26 & 0.38\\
  Decision tree & 0.72 & 0.25 & 0.56 & 0.34 & 0.46\\
  Random Forest & 0.77 & 0.27 & 0.43 & 0.33 & 0.38\\
  XGBoost & 0.71 & 0.27 & 0.75 & 0.4 & 0.56\\
  CatBoost & 0.70 & 0.27 & 0.75 & 0.39 & 0.55\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Results using Weight Attention Data Set.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput of the above code]

Comment: Following your example I adapted my previous solution and manage to obtain the result that I wanted ! Thanks a lot